# how to exclude required entities from a response in TypeORM with NestJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have an entity

```
@Column()
name: string;

@IsEmail()
email: string;

@Column({ select: false })
autogeneratedCode: string;
```

I'm getting name and string only in my GET request response which is expected.

But when I'm hit my POST Api with body, it is returning `name`, `email`, `autogeneratedCode` as well.

I need to hide autogeneratedCode in all CRUD responses.

Is there anyway to do that? or Am I missing something here?

Comment: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization#exclude-properties

Comment: I tried this, it's not working for @Post()

Comment: did you add the constructor to your entity like in the example.  After saving the entity to the database you have to create a new object with the constructor to exclude the `@Exclude()` properties.  Ex: return new User(this.userRepository.save(entity));`.   Just added an answer with a more fleshed out example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Exclude()` from 'class-transformer'

**Example**

```js
import { Exclude } from 'class-transformer';

@Entity()
export class User {
  @Column()
  name: string;

  @IsEmail()
  email: string;

  @Column({ select: false })
  @Exclude()
  autogeneratedCode: string;

  constructor(entity: Partial<User>) {
    Object.assign(this, entity);
  }
}
```

Then you can use the constructor to create a new object excluding the `@Exclude()` properties.

```js
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private userRepository: Repository<User>
  ) {}

  public async createUser(user: User): Promise<User> {
    return new User(
      await this.userRepository.save(user)
    );
  }
}
```

**NestJS Doc on Serialization**

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization#exclude-properties